# Solve for 2D translation, rotation and scale given two touch point movements

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

For a phone app I need to let users translate, rotate and scale a rectangle on the 2D plane using "pinch" gesture.

Suppose the rectangle already has TRS = $t, \theta, s $; and the user has their fingers on two touch points $p_1, p_2$.  The user then moves the touch points to  $q_1, q_2$. What is the new TRS that will map $p_1 \rightarrow q_1, p_2 \rightarrow q_2$.  In other words, the user should feel that their fingers are "stuck" to the rectangle. The scale is always the same for $x$ and $y$.

The scale is easy. Let $p=p_1 - p_2$ and  $q=q_1 - q_2$, then  $s' = s \cdot  \dfrac{||q||}{||p||}  $

I think rotation is can use the arcSine of the cross product. Let $q_\bot = (-q_y, q_x)$ and
$\Delta\theta = arcSine \dfrac{q_\bot\cdot p}{||q||\cdot||p||}$, then $\theta' = \theta + \Delta\theta$

I think the translation should preserve the midpoint. So: $t' = t +  \frac{1}{2}((q_1 - p_1)+(q_2 - p_2))$.

But when I implement this, it doesn't work very well. The rotation is not around the correct point so the rectangle seems to slide away strangely.  Any advice please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some background.  Let's review the underlying math and notation.

Transformation $\mathbf{T}$ has four free parameters: scale $\lambda$, rotation $\theta$, and translation by $(t_x, t_y)$.  Let's define the transformation of point $\vec{p} = (p_x , p_y)$ to point $\vec{q} = (q_x , q_y)$ as
$$\vec{q} = \mathbf{T} \vec{p} \quad \iff \quad
\left[ \begin{matrix} q_x \\ q_y \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} 
\lambda \cos \theta & -\lambda \sin \theta & t_x \\
\lambda \sin \theta & \lambda \cos \theta & t_y \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} p_x \\ p_y \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{1a}\label{G1a}$$
Defining the transform as a single matrix $\mathbf{T}$ as
$$\mathbf{T} = \left[ \begin{matrix} \lambda \cos \theta & -\lambda \sin \theta & t_x \\
\lambda \sin \theta & \lambda \cos \theta & t_y \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{1b}\label{G1b}$$
is useful, because we can calculate the inverse ($\vec{p} = \mathbf{T}^{-1} \vec{q}$),
$$\mathbf{T}^{-1} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\frac{\cos\theta}{\lambda} & \frac{\sin\theta}{\lambda} & - \frac{t_x \cos\theta + t_y \sin\theta}{\lambda} \\
- \frac{\sin\theta}{\lambda} & \frac{\cos\theta}{\lambda} & \frac{t_x \sin\theta - t_y \cos\theta}{\lambda} \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right] \tag{1c}\label{G1c}$$
and combine transformations via matrix multiplication:
$$\mathbf{T}_\text{combined} = \mathbf{T}_\text{after} \mathbf{T}_\text{before} \tag{1d}\label{G1d}$$
where the rightmost transformation is applied first, and leftmost transformation last.  Note that the identity transform, "no transform" or "as-is", is
$$\mathbf{1} = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right] \tag{1e}\label{G1e}$$
This way we can also "ignore" the current transform ($\mathbf{T}_\text{before}$) for the purposes here, and just calculate the transform $\mathbf{T}_\text{after}$ caused by the gesture here; and get the combined transform using $\eqref{G1d}$.

(Note that such $3 \times 3$ matrices (with only $2 \times 3$ elements actually stored) are commonly used in 2D computer graphics, including [SVG transform matrix() attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined), with the third component ($1$) of vectors not stored, and just baked in to the functions doing matrix-vector multiplication.  Similarly for $4 \times 4$ matrices (with only $3 \times 4$ elements actually stored) for 3D computer graphics, including OpenGL.)

The problem is to find the transformation $\mathbf{T}$ that transforms $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$ to $\vec{q}_1$ and $\vec{q}_2$,
$$\left\lbrace \, \begin{aligned}
\vec{q}_1 &= \mathbf{T} \vec{p}_1 \\
\vec{q}_2 &= \mathbf{T} \vec{p}_2 \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{2}\label{G2}$$
which is actually a set of four equations (two Cartesian components per vector), and four unknowns (that define $\mathbf{T}$), and therefore should have a single solution (except for degenerate cases, where $\vec{p}_1 = \vec{p}_2$ or something similar).

Note that because of finite precision of floating-point numbers, we do not want to apply the transformation incrementally.  That is, we should remember the very initial touch points $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$, keeping them unchanged for the duration of the gesture, also remembering the original transformation $\mathbf{T}_\text{before}$, compute a *temporary* gesture transformation $\mathbf{T}_\text{gesture}$ based on the initial touch points $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$ and current touch points $\vec{q}_1$ and $\vec{q}_2$, and a *temporary* currently applied transformation $\mathbf{T}_\text{temp} = \mathbf{T}_\text{gesture}$.  Only when the gesture is finished, will the final $\mathbf{T}_\text{temp}$ become the currently applied and stored transformation.

If you apply the transformation incrementally, i.e. $\vec{p}_1$, $\vec{p}_2$ corresponding to the previous touch locations, and $\vec{q}_1$, $\vec{q}_2$ corresponding to current touch locations, and continously apply $\mathbf{T}_\text{current} = \mathbf{T}_\text{gesture} \mathbf{T}_\text{previous}$, not only do your rounding errors compound (making the gesture control *erratic*), but it will also be *jittery*, because small movement of one finger when close to the other will cause large rotations; the faster your touch pad update rate, the more likely such small movements are.  The incremental moment-to-moment transformation approach just does not work in practice.

---

Let $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$ be the initial touch points, and $\vec{q}_1$ and $\vec{q}_2$ the corresponding final positions:
$$\vec{p}_1 = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right], \;
\vec{p}_2 = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right], \;
\vec{q}_1 = \left[ \begin{matrix} \chi_1 \\ \gamma_1 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right], \;
\vec{q}_2 = \left[ \begin{matrix} \chi_2 \\ \gamma_2 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right]$$
Let $C = \lambda \cos \theta$, $S = \lambda \sin \theta$, and translation is by $(X, Y)$, so that the transformation matrix is
$$\mathbf{T} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
C & -S & X \\
S &  C & Y \\
0 &  0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right] \tag{3a}\label{G3a}$$
Note that as long $C S \ne 0$, the upper left $2 \times 2$ matrix is a proper rotation and scaling matrix, for all $C \in \mathbb{R}$, $S \in \mathbb{R}$.  The vector $(C, S)$ is the new $x$ axis basis vector, and $(-S, C)$ the new $y$ axis basis vector, and the two are always perpendicular (with positive $y$ axis 90° counterclockwise from positive $x$ acis) and have the same length.

Substituting these into $\eqref{G2}$ we have four equations and four unknowns ($C$, $S$, $X$, and $Y$), which has exactly one solution:
$$\left\lbrace \, \begin{aligned}
L^2 &= (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \\
C &= \frac{ (\chi_2 - \chi_1)(x_2 - x_1) + (\gamma_2 - \gamma_1)(y_2 - y_1) }{L^2} \\
S &= \frac{ (\gamma_2 - \gamma_1)(x_2 - x_1) - (\chi_2 - \chi_1)(y_2 - y_1) }{L^2} \\
X &= \frac{ (x_2 - x_1)(\chi_1 x_2 - \chi_2 x_1) + (y_2 - y_1)(\chi_1 y_2 - \chi_2 y_1) + (\gamma_2 - \gamma_1)(x_2 y_1 - x_1 y_2) }{L^2} \\
Y &= \frac{ (\chi_2 - \chi_1)(x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1) + (y_2 - y_1)(\gamma_1 y_2 - \gamma_2 y_1) + (x_2 - x_1)(\gamma_1 x_2 - \gamma_2 x_1) }{L^2} \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{3b}\label{G3b}$$

If we do need the angle $\theta$ and the scale factor $\lambda$, they are obviously
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\lambda &= \sqrt{C^2 + S^2} \\
\theta &= \operatorname{atan2}\left(S, C\right) \\
\cos\theta &= \displaystyle \frac{C}{\sqrt{C^2 + S^2}} \\
\sin\theta &= \displaystyle \frac{S}{\sqrt{C^2 + S^2}} \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{3c}\label{G3c}$$
where $\operatorname{atan2}$ is the two-parameter form of arcus tangent, provided by almost all programming languages. ($\operatorname{atan2}(y, x) = \arctan(y/x)$ for $x \gt 0$, but is valid for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ except $x=0, y=0$, as it takes the signs of both $x$ and $y$ into account in other quadrants.  Typically, it returns the angle in radians between $-\pi$ (-180°) and $+\pi$ (+180°), but it may vary between programming languages.)

---

We can verify the above using
$$\vec{o} = \left[\begin{matrix} o_x \\ o_y \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right], ~
\vec{t} = \left[\begin{matrix} t_x \\ t_y \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right], ~
\vec{b} = \left[\begin{matrix} b_x \\ b_y \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right], ~
\vec{a} = \left[\begin{matrix} a_x \\ a_y \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
and
$$\vec{p}_1 = \vec{o} + \vec{b}, ~ ~
\vec{p}_2 = \vec{o} - \vec{b}, ~ ~
\vec{q}_1 = \vec{o} + \vec{t} + \vec{a}, ~ ~
\vec{q}_2 = \vec{o} + \vec{t} - \vec{a}$$
so that $\vec{o}$ represents the middle point between the two initial touch points, $\vec{b}$ represents the vector from the middle point to the first initial touch point and $-\vec{b}$ the vector from the middle point to the second initial touch point, $\vec{t}$ represents the translation, and $\vec{a}$ represents the vector from the middle point between the final touch points ($\vec{o}+\vec{t}$) to the first final touch point, and $-\vec{a}$ the vector from the middle point between the final touch points to the second final touch point.  The transformation matrix is then
$$\mathbf{T} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\displaystyle \frac{a_x b_x + a_y b_y}{b_x^2 + b_y^2} & \displaystyle \frac{a_x b_y - a_y b_x}{b_x^2 + b_y^2} & \displaystyle t_x + o_x - \frac{o_x (a_x b_x + a_y b_y ) + o_y (a_x b_y - a_y b_x )}{b_x^2 + b_y^2} \\
\displaystyle \frac{a_y b_x - a_x b_y}{b_x^2 + b_y^2} & \displaystyle \frac{a_x b_x + a_y b_y}{b_x^2 + b_y^2} & \displaystyle t_y + o_y - \frac{ o_x ( a_y b_x - a_x b_y ) + o_y (a_x b_x + a_y b_y ) }{b_x^2 + b_y^2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]$$
and if we do the math, we indeed find that $\mathbf{T} \vec{p}_1 = \vec{q}_1$ and $\mathbf{T} \vec{p}_2 = \vec{q}_2$.

---

Note that we can extract rotation angle, scale factor, and translation from such a $3 \times 3$ matrix (assuming it is orthogonal, not skewed) with entries
$$\mathbf{M} = \left[ \begin{matrix} m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\ m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right] \tag{4}\label{G4a}$$
via
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\theta &= \operatorname{atan2}\left( m_{21} - m_{22} ,\, m_{11} + m_{22} \right) \\
\lambda &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{m_{11}^2 + m_{21}^2} + \sqrt{m_{12}^2 + m_{22}^2}\right) \\
t_x &= X = m_{13} \\
t_y &= Y = m_{23} \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{4b}\label{G4b}$$
In particular, if you have an existing transfrom (by $\theta_1$, $\lambda_1$, $(X_1, Y_1)$), and you wish to further transform it (by $\theta_2$, $\lambda_2$, $(X_2, Y_2)$), first construct the two matrices using
$$\mathbf{M} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\lambda \cos\theta & -\lambda \sin\theta & X \\
\lambda \sin\theta & \lambda \cos\theta & Y \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{4c}\label{G4c}$$
then calculate their product via matrix multiplication, original orientation rightmost, latest applied transform leftmost,
$$\mathbf{M}_\text{final} = \mathbf{M}_2 \mathbf{M}_1$$
and then extract the rotation angle $\theta$, scale factor $\lambda$, and translation $(X, Y)$ as specified in $\eqref{G4b}$.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. I think you're right, I should not try to do incremental updates.  You have given me the answer for T (the combined transform) and you explain how to extract the rotation and scale.  However I am using the android Canvas api (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) which does NOT have any setMatrix method. It only has rotate/translate/scale.  Yes I know, it's a stupid api!  Anyway I have to figure out how to extract the translation. Is it simply X,Y from your equation (3b) above?  Thanks again!  Great work!

Comment: @JohnHenckel: Yes, $(X, Y)$ is the translation (from $\eqref{G3b}$); $\lambda$ is the scale (same for $x$ and $y$ axes) and $\theta$ the rotation around origin (from $\eqref{G3c}$ after $\eqref{G3b}$ has been done).  Don't you have [Canvas.concat()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#concat(android.graphics.Matrix)) either?  If not, I can show you how to extract the rotation, scale, and translation (applied eiter RST or SRT, i.e. scale or rotation first, and translation last) from the matrix, so you can keep the matrix representation internally.

Comment: @JohnHenckel:  I added a short section on extracting the four variables (rotation angle $\theta$, scale factor $\lambda$, and translation $(X, Y)$) from an existing matrix.  This way, if you have an existing transformation to which you wish to apply the gesture transformation, you can convert the old one to a matrix, combine the two (or any number!) in matrix form via matrix-matrix multiplication (do you need it explicitly written out term-by-term?), and obtain the combined final transform also in $\theta$, $\lambda$, $(X, Y)$ form.

Comment: thanks for that. I was wrong about the canvas; it does have `setMatrix`, so that's good. I might keep the TRS separated anyway. The coordinates for p and q are taken from touch sensors, which are in device coordinates.  however, I think I cannot use those in (3d) correct? I must first apply T(before) to both p and q. Then I can use that to compute T(after) using (3d).  Also I just discovered the `android.graphics.Matrix` class has many really useful methods `setScale`, `postRotate`, and `postTranslate` that will basically do the job of (3d).

Comment: @JohnHenckel: You can use device coordinates directly, but it would be better to scale the touch coordinates first (by a single adjustable factor), so that one unit in touch coordinates translates one logical unit in world space; meaning, that scale factor should be user-configurable (a slider?).  Typically, an initial factor of 1.0 (raw device coordinates) should work "okay"; not best, but okay.  Then, you can use the resulting combined matrix as is, for world transformations.  You do *not* apply $T$ to the touch coordinates, ever!

Comment: Hurray!!!! I finally got this working last night, after an embarrassing number of hours with a lot more trial and error than I want to admit. I see what you mean by *jittery*. I may need to apply a smoothing function to the translation. I'll post some sample code after I clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested in a less rigorous, but more practical answer, here is the source code that I used with the `android.graphics.Canvas`.

First I made a class called `Transform` as follows (Vec2 is just two floats)

```
public class Transform
{
    Vec2 translation;
    Vec2 center;
    float rotation;
    float scale;

    Matrix getMatrix()
    {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setTranslate(center.x, center.y);
        m.preRotate(degrees(rotation));
        m.preScale(scale, scale);
        m.preTranslate(translation.x - center.x, translation.y - center.y);
        return m;
    }
}
```

Then I made an `OnTouchListener` that captures two vectors, **p** and **q** at the start and end of the pinch gesture.

[image]

The method `OnTouchListener.getTransform` returns a `Transform` with translation (the green vector), center (the red vector), rotation (the angle from p to q), scale (length of q over p). Both vectors are in *device* coordinates (blue).

In the `MainView.onDraw(Canvas)` method I apply the transform as follows:

```
    transform = touchListener.getTransform();
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(transform.center.x, transform.center.y);
    canvas.rotate(degrees(transform.rotation));
    canvas.scale(transform.scale, transform.scale);
    canvas.translate(transform.translation.x - transform.center.x,
                     transform.translation.y - transform.center.y);
    mainWorld.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

If I want, I can instead use the matrix as follows,

```
    transform = touchListener.getTransform();
    currentMatrix = transform.getMatrix();
    canvas.save();
    canvas.setMatrix(currentMatrix);
    mainWorld.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

During the gesture, I may want to keep the current matrix separate from the previous matrix. In that case I would apply both of them as follows,

```
    canvas.save();
    canvas.setMatrix(currentMatrix);
    canvas.concat(previousMatrix);
    mainWorld.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

At the end of the gesture, I merge the current into the previous matrix,

```
    previousMatrix.postConcat(currentMatrix);
```

Here are some utilities to extract the transform from a matrix.

```
public static float getAngleFromMatrix(Matrix matrix)
{
    float[] m = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float c = m[0] + m[4];
    float s = m[3] - m[1];
    return MathUtils.atan2(s,c);
}

public static float getScaleFromMatrix(Matrix matrix)
{
    float[] m = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(m);
    return 0.5f * (MathUtils.sqrt(m[0]*m[0] + m[1]*m[1]) + MathUtils.sqrt(m[3]*m[3] + m[4]*m[4]));
}

public static Vec2 getTranslationFromMatrix(Matrix matrix)
{
    float[] m = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(m);
    return new Vec2(m[2], m[5]);
}
```